# In RStudio, how to navigate the panels of the commit window with the keyboard

Tags: r, git, rstudio

Consider the "Review Changes" window of RStudio. Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump from the staging area directly into the "Commit message" area?

When I am ready to commit, I work on the staging area first. (So it is great that the "Review Changes" window pops up with the staging area activated.) But then I commonly need to jump to the "Commit message" area. To jump to the "Commit message" area, I do one of these two inefficient things:

- Click on the "Commit message" area -- which I prefer to avoid because it takes my hand out of the keyboard;
- Hit the Tab key 10 times -- which I prefer to avoid because it takes too long.

Anyone has more efficient solution?

Comment: If you're hell bent on the keyboard, may I suggest the terminal to do all your git related stuff?

Comment: Thanks! That's a good suggestion -- with RStudio 1.1.383 I can open a terminal with Shift+Alt+R and start typing right away. (Unfortunately, the number of keystrokes I'll need to press is about the same as hitting Tab 10 times.) I suspect I might be able to write an addin and link a shortcut to it.

Comment: @MauroLepore, I was looking for something similar. If you use `Shift+Tab`, you only need to press Tab 3 times! Not an ideal solution, but it works!